# Filtering in join in supabase

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, filtering, supabase

Im using supabase with a database which have 2 tables (that are implicates in this issue).
Tables are `teachers` and `users`. Both have `ID` and `id_teacher`/`id_user` respectively.
Im working in a query where i need to get all teacher, joining in `users` table, where theres a `image` column.
I need just to get the `teachers` where the `user` have an **not null** `image`.

```
    const query = supabase.from(`teachers`).select(
      `
        *,
        id_user(
          image
        )
      `
    )
```

This query works to get teachers joining in users table. Because i get my wanted response.
This is a short example.

```
{
    "id": 560,
    "teacher_experience": 9,
    "id_user":{
        "image": "example-image.jpg"
    }
}
```

The trouble is when i try to use some filter to avoid **null** `images`.

```
query.not('id_user.image', 'eq', null)
query.not('id_user.image', 'in', null)
query.ilike('id_user.image', 'null')
```

Are just an examples o filters tha i tryed for avoid the teachers which `user.image` have a **null** value.
Because, i want to NOT GET the entire item, but i get an item wiht a `id_user = null`

```
{
    "id": 560,
    "teacher_experience": 9,
    "id_user": null          // In this case image is null but still giving me the user
}
```

How is the correct form to solve this?

Comment: Try this option you are missing select function which is used to select before applying filter : query.select().not('id_user.image', 'in', null). Ref : https://supabase.io/docs/reference/javascript/not

Answer (score 18):

This has now been implemented with PostgREST 9!

Here's an example:

```
const { data, error } = await supabase
  .from('messages')
  .select('*, users!inner(*)')
  .eq('users.username', 'Jane'
```

In your, case you'd have to do `id_user!inner(image)`

Source: https://supabase.com/blog/postgrest-9#resource-embedding-with-inner-joins

Answer (score 3):

[Just create](https://supabase.io/new/blog/2020/11/18/postgresql-views) a `view` in database for solve this problem. A `view` is a shortcut to queries and it possible apply `where` clause.

In sql editor on supabase [https://app.supabase.io/project/{your_project_id}/editor/sql](https://app.supabase.io/project/%7Byour_project_id%7D/editor/sql)

create a new view with joins;

```
CREATE VIEW teachers_view AS
SELECT
    t.*,
    iu.image as image
FROM teachers as t
LEFT JOIN id_user as iu WHERE t.id = iu.teacher_id;
```

read more about left join [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_using_joins.htm#:%7E:text=2%20%7C%20Allen%20%7C%20Engineering-,The%20LEFT%20OUTER%20JOIN,-The%20OUTER%20JOIN)

and in application use

```
supabase.from('teachers_view').select().neq('image', null);
```

Comment: that should read "as ui ON t.id" ...

Comment: The link on this answer returns a 404. It should link to: https://supabase.com/blog/postgresql-views

Answer (score 2):

This feature came up recently with the release of the [support for PostgREST 9](https://supabase.com/blog/2021/11/28/postgrest-9#resource-embedding-with-inner-joins). You have to use `!inner` keyword, you can now filter rows of the top-level table.

```
   const query = supabase.from(`teachers`).select(
      `
        *,
        id_user!inner(image)
      `
    ).not("id_users.image", "is", "NULL")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
query.not("your_column_name", "is", "NULL")
```

worked for me!

odd enough, if you want to check for NULL

```
.filter("your_column_name", "is", "NULL")
```

seems to be the solution. No idea why it's not consistent

Comment: Is a embebed column, and is not posiblle atm
https://github.com/supabase/supabase/discussions/3155#discussioncomment-1310299

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible atm.
[You can see state of issue here.](https://github.com/supabase/supabase/discussions/3155#discussioncomment-1310299)
Some posibilities are using `views` o start the query in the other table.

Answer (score 0):

The Supabase client uses `postgrest`, so you can use all sorts of operators in your queries.  [See this page as a reference](https://postgrest.org/en/v7.0.0/api.html?highlight=operators#operators).

Answer (score 0):

you can try like with inner joins by using the !inner operator in select

```
 const query = supabase.from(`teachers`).select(
  `
    *,
    id_user!inner(
      image
    )
  `
)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).